# python speech recognizer recognize_ibm deprecated, alternative?

Tags: python, speech-to-text, websphere

Since january the recognize_ibm function is not working anymore, due to IBM changing their authorization system. Since it was pretty fast compared to google, I was wondering if there is anything one can do to make it work with the new authorization system, or eventually an alternative api for python.
Here is my code (I am not adding the credentials here, obviously):

```
def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""
        try:
            said = r.recognize_ibm(audio, username=IBM_USERNAME, password=IBM_PASSWORD)
            winsound.PlaySound("SystemAsterisk", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return said
```

Thanks